¿Cómo combinar un archivo de excel con una carpeta de imágenes en VBA?
Necesito crear una macro donde tengo una base en excel y relacionarla con una carpeta de imágenes. Los nombres de las imágenes y una columna de la base tienen identificadores que los puedes relacionar. La macro al dar clic en el botón, debe insertar la imagen con el nombre que coincide con la cadena que se encuentra en la celda, en la celda contigua o de a lado. De ésta forma quedan ligadas las imágenes con el identificador.
Private Sub cmdFusion_Click()
    
    Dim Col As New Collection
    Dim ruta As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oCarpeta As Object
    Dim oArchivo As Object
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim idArt As String, idArt2 As String
    Dim name As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False   
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Title = "Seleccionar carpeta"
        .Show

        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set oCarpeta = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\SET\OneDrive\Escritorio\Ricardo\Archivo Union Imagenes\Images\")
        For Each oArchivo In oCarpeta.Files
            ruta = oArchivo
            If Mid(ruta, 71, 1) = "\" Then
                idArt = Mid(ruta, 72, 6)
                idArt2 = idArt
                MsgBox idArt
            End If
        Next oArchivo
    End With
    
    Dim archivo2 As String
    Dim iRow As Long, iRow2 As String, resultado As Integer
    
    archivo2 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", , "Seleccionar el archivo de Catalog")
    If archivo2 = "Falso" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set book2 = Workbooks.Open(archivo2)
    
    Dim nFilas As Long, nColumnas As Long
    Dim Fila As Long, Columna As Long
    Dim Valor As Long
    Dim Rango As Range
    Dim vArray() As Long
    Dim IniciarTiempo As Double
    
    nFilas = [iRow2]
    nColumnas = [idArt2]
    
    ReDim vArray(2 To nFilas, 2 To nColumnas)
    Set Rango = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(nFilas, nColumnas))
    
    Valor = iRow2
    iRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To iRow
        iRow2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        MsgBox (iRow2)  'MsgBox ("hola")
            For j = ruta To idArt2
                vArray(Fila, Columna) = Valor
                Valor = Valor + 1
            Next j
    Next i
    Rango.Value = vArray

    
    MsgBox ("Proceso Terminado")

End Sub


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y cual es el problema???

Lo que yo haría es recorrer la carpeta en cuestion y almacenar los nombres de las imágenes en un array/diccionario. Luego, recorrer las filas de tu tabla y comprobar si el identificador tiene su correspondiente correlación con algún nombre del array/diccionario. Si es así sólo hay que insertar en una celda contigua la ruta de la carpeta, el nombre de la imagen y crear un un hipervínculo a esa ruta.
